# Global Regular Expression in Lua Script

Tags: luatex, lua

I have the below LaTeX coding in whole my document and want to do convert globally:

```
\author{Bronnikov Kirill A{$^{1}$}{$^{2}$}{$^{3}$}}

\author{Santos N O{$^{4}$}{$^{5}$}}

\author{Wang Anzhong{$^{6}$}{$^{7}$}{$^{8}$}}{$^{9}$}}
```

should be

```
\author{Kirill A Bronnikov{$^{1}$}, {$^{2}$} and {$^{3}$}}

\author{N O Santos{$^{4}$} and {$^{5}$}}

\author{Anzhong Wang{$^{6}$}, {$^{7}$}, {$^{8}$}} and {$^{9}$}}
```

My Lua Script is:

```
TeXInput=string.gsub(TeXInput,[[{%$%^{(.-)}%$}{%$%^{(.-)}%$}]],[[{$^{%1}$},{$^{%2}$}]])
```

But this is converting single place only and how to add final `and` text using Lua?

Comment: gsub does not take regular expression syntax (Lua does not have regexp by default although there are packages you can add with regex implementations)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Could you please advise the regex package name for further implementations? How to add final `and` text in the `regex`?

Comment: It is a pattern not a regex but patterns are quite powerful enough here, I added an answer but the question seems strange you just match the third part in exactly the same way as you match the first two, I simply cut and pasted your code so it had three clauses not two?

Comment: why are you marking author footnotes using math mode at all? you should surely be using `\thanks` or `\footnote` shouldn't you????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Okay i will use `\footnote` instead of math mode. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be `%$}{%$`. Note that dollar signs, which have special meaning in Lua regular expressions, are escaped with per cent signs, which is the escape character.

You have to apply this regex twice: firstly, to insert commas, limiting the number of replacements to the number of patterns less one, secondly, to insert the "and".

`string:gmatch` will return the iterator, that can be used to count the number of needed separators, and `string:gsub` will do the replacements.

```lua
local tex = '{$^{1}$}{$^{2}$}{$^{3}$}'

local function commafy (text)
    local pattern = '%$}{%$'
    local count = 0
    for _ in tex:gmatch (pattern) do
        count = count + 1
    end
    return tex:gsub (pattern, '$}, {$', count - 1):gsub (pattern, '$} and {$')
end

print (commafy (tex))
```

Comment: Your solutions is working fine. But i have many function tags. My previous Lua code is `tex.sprint(TeXInput)`. How to add your function and combine with all is single `tex.spring(TeXInput)?. And also how to change the author name. Please check my question is modified.

Comment: If your environment allows multiline Lua scripts then copy the function `commafy` into your Lua script and then `TeXInput = commafy(TeXInput)`. If it ought to be a one-liner, then try `TeXInput = (function(t) local pattern = '%$}{%$'; local count = 0; for _ in t:gmatch (pattern) do count = count + 1 end; return t:gsub (pattern, '$}, {$', count - 1):gsub (pattern, '$} and {$') end)(TeXInput)`.
I don't understand what exactly you mean by 'many function tags'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your example matches all occurrences not just the first

testlua.tex

```
{$^{1}$}{$^{2}$}{$^{3}$}

{$^{a}$}{$^{b}$}{$^{c}$}
```

and a Lua file

```
local f = io.open("testlua.tex")
local TeXInput = f:read("*a")
f:close()

TeXInput=string.gsub(TeXInput,
[[{%$%^{(.-)}%$}{%$%^{(.-)}%$}{%$%^{(.-)}%$}]],
[[{$^{%1}$},{$^{%2}$} and {$^{%3}$}]])

print(TeXInput)
```

Produces this terminal output

```
$ texlua dd316.lua

{$^{1}$},{$^{2}$} and {$^{3}$}

{$^{a}$},{$^{b}$} and {$^{c}$}
```

Comment: I have seen your code and my code is same. I have modified my question. This is actually i have need the final output including author name changes. How to achieve this?